# C# functions with static data

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

In VB.Net, I can declare a variable in a function as Static, like this:

```
Function EncodeForXml(ByVal data As String) As String
    Static badAmpersand As Regex = new Regex("&(?![a-zA-Z]{2,6};|#[0-9]{2,4};)")

    data = badAmpersand.Replace(data, "&amp;")

    ''// more processing

    return data
End Function
```

Note that I need to use the keyword `Static`, rather than `Shared`, which is the normal way to express this in VB.Net.  How can I do this in C#?  I can't find its equivalent.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ha! In posting the question, I found the answer!  Rather than googling for C# I should have been looking for details on how VB.Net implements it, and typing up the question made that apparent to me.  After applying that insight, I found this:
http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/articles/7717.aspx

That article explains that it's not really supported by the CLR, and the VB compiler creates a static (shared) variable "under the hood" in the method's class.  To do the same in C#, I have to create the variable myself.

More than that, it uses the `Monitor` class to make sure the static member is thread-safe as well.  Nice.

As a side note:  I'd expect to see this in C# sometime soon.  The general tactic I've observed from MS is that it doesn't like VB.Net and C# to get too far apart feature-wise.   If one language has a feature not supported by the other it tends to become a priority for the language team for the next version.

Comment: And to think, I was going to pimp my own blog (where I addressed this a couple months ago) ... But you've saved me the trouble, and that entry is considerably more clear than my own. Thanks for the link!

Comment: You can also check out the IL/C# code generated from VB using reflector, I notice that sometime ago. It's also fun to see what some VB tricks are possible done in C#

Answer (score 6):

Personally I'm glad that C# *doesn't* have this. Logically, methods don't have state: types and instances do. C# makes that logical model clearer, IMO.

Comment: Agreed that using this to save state with a method is a bad idea. Note that in this case the purpose is to make sure the creation/compilation of the regex happen only once. You could say this is a form of state, but I think here it's really about performance, not keeping data between method calls.

Comment: In that case it's fine just to be a static readonly field. It's a piece of immutable state associated with the type, initialized when the type is initialized. Make sense as a static to me :)

Comment: I take it you haven't worked with Closures yet. They literally are mutable state being stored in a method.

Comment: Yes, I certainly have worked with closures - but I regard those as encapsulating "method + environment" rather than just a method. (The state itself is stored in a separate class where necessary.)

Answer (score 4):

There is no equivalent in C# unfortunately.

You will need to use a class level variable.

This is one of the few things that VB has that I wish C# had.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare this on the class level:

```
private static readonly RegEx badAmpersand = new RegEx("...");
```

Comment: That should work in this case, but in the general sense it's more complicated than that because there could be concurrency issues in a multi-threaded app.  The VB.Net Static member is supposed to be thread-safe.